# How to render a react component on / api route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, backend

I have this API route like this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

what i want is when the user goes to that route. I want it to render a react component. But when i call that component like this

```
const {VideoChat} = require("../src/VideoChat");

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('VideoChat');
});
```

it gives me an error that says

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'; ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Component looks like this :-
`videoChat.js

```
const VideoChat = () => {

  let render;
  if (token) {
    render = (
      <Room roomName={roomName} token={token} handleLogout={handleLogout} />
    );
  } else {
    render = (
      <Lobby
        username={username}
        roomName={roomName}
        handleUsernameChange={handleUsernameChange}
        handleRoomNameChange={handleRoomNameChange}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      />
    );
  }
  return render;
};

export default VideoChat;
```

Comment: I can't understand what you want to do. API route and client side route is different.

Comment: I have this react component. it is a form basically. I want that whenever the user goes to the `/` url, that component should be rendered.

Comment: Just wanna know that how do i tell the server that when the user is on `/` then load that component.

Comment: your word doesn't have got sense. `I have got api route. when user goes to that route`???

Comment: Does you project contain Babel?

Comment: @ZaidUlAbedeen No

Comment: Then please try adding following to your package.json file:
 ` "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.2.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.6.1"
  },`

and then `npm install`